# Selenium python, Click only under certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code works, but not in all cases
Basically the functionality is to click a load_more button until it no longer appears.

As of right now, I simply have a loop which finds the loadmore button and clicks it twice, but there are cases that it will click on something else when the load more button disappears.

I was planning on making a while loop, which would constantly find the click the load_more option until the loadmore disappeared then break the loop.

Here is the code: (This simply finds and clicks it twice)

```
load_more = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#mainContent > div.left-panel > div > div.result-list > div > div.content")
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of(load_more))

#Need bugfix, 
for i in range(2):
    browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", load_more)
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(load_more).click().perform()
```

I noticed when playing around with the load more button that.

```
<div class="progressbtnwrap" data-search-type="search" style="display: block;">
```

When the load more button is present on the site, the element is set to "display: block;"

But once the load more button disappears,

```
<div class="progressbtnwrap" data-search-type="search" style="display: none;">
```

the element changes to none, notice "display: none;"

Any suggestions how I can search for this?

When looking through the selenium documentations I couldn't find any way of searching for this element and specifically checking if the style is triggered to none,

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

My goal here is to create something like this

```
while(True):
    if browser.find_element_by_notsurewhat == "block":
        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(load_more).click().perform()
    if browser.find_element_by_notsurewhat == "none":
        break
    browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", load_more)
```

I'm sure the logic must be much more complicated than that, or even if what I want to achieve is even possible, Any suggestions would be amazing!

Thank you all!

UPDATE:

```
def load_more(browser):
    print("I'm in the function LOAD MORE")
    try:
        if browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div'):
            print("I HAVE ENTERED THE TRY BLOCK WITHIN THE LOAD MORE FUNCTION")
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    return False
while load_more(browser):
    print("I'm in the while loop!")
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(load_more).click().perform()
    browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", load_more)
```

When placing my locating and clicking commands, I began to receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\eclipse-workspace\Web_Scrap\setup.py", line 81, in <module>
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(load_more).click().perform()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 83, in perform
    action()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 293, in <lambda>
    Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I noticed from trying to figure out exactly where the program crashes that, once the code below is run, the program crashes, but this works prior to placing this inside the while loop, or the function. (I tried to place the scrollIntoView, line inside the function right before the try, and I receive a similar error).

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(load_more).click().perform()
browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", load_more)
```

[image: Load more button visible]

[image: Load more button Gone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the style attribute for an html element is set to display: none, selenium won't be able to find the element using the built-in DOM selector functions like find_element_by_id/find_elements_by_class etc.
You could simply wrap the find operation in a try except block and add a  delay to allow the browser some time for the Ajax call.

```
def load_more(browser):
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        display = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('progressbtnwrap')[0].style.display")
        if display == 'none':
            return False
        elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "progressbtnwrap")]/div[contains(@class, "content")]')
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error")
        print(e)
    return False

while load_more(browser):
    print("scrolling further")
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I really appreciate it!, when trying the code I did receive the following error,                                               Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /div[contains(@class, "progressbtnwrap"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/div[contains(@class, "progressbtnwrap"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I will go back into the element section and copy the xpath from there and see if that works out

Comment: Correction, i've updated the typo in the xpath string.

Comment: I tried out the correction, but the function hits the except, I have copied the xpath from the website and placed it inside, and receive the error in the updated section of my post :(

Comment: Also, the load more button itself is a different element from the xpath that I have posted, the xpath that I have posted, is the element that changes names when the load more button disappears, I'm not sure if that would make  adifference I will post a picture in the post so you can get an idea of what i'm talking about

Comment: Could you share the url?

Comment: http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=schoolId&schoolName=California+State+University%2C+Northridge&schoolID=163&queryoption=TEACHER

Comment: Have updated my response, used JS for element click and worked for me!
Let me know if any issues found

Comment: Good news! this works!, only problem now is it doesn't break out of the loop after the load more disappears :D, also would it be possible to explain to me how you found that xpath?

Comment: Updated code, checks the display property for `none` to break the click loop. Use developer tools, and refer to https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath for more information on XPath

Comment: thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it!, I will definitely check out that link for the xpath information

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to do this is to use "explicit waits" (AKA `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions`).

The following will wait until the element is no longer visible.  If it doesn't disappear in 10 secs, a `TimeOutError` is raised:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'progressbtnwrap'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are currently just trying to find a way on how you can check the current style of your element you can use this code.

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].style.display;", load_more)
```

And you can use to check that when the return value is 'none' for a few seconds which means no more data will be loaded, you can exit your loop.